# ImageView is not always transparent and white space is shown instead

Tags: java, android, xml, imagebutton

I have problem with `ImageButton`

`ImageView` has white space on a phone, and in another one not. Why is that?

I need transparent `ImageView` on all phones.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/large"
    android:layout_weight="0.66"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/stuUP"
        android:layout_weight="1.1"
        android:onClick="BtnstuUP"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:src="@mipmap/btup"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Do you have any idea on where the problem is? Below are two screenshots (`Display 1` and `Display 2`) for further explanation.

## Display 1 Xiaomi Mi3 - Bad View

[image]

## Display 2 Acer Z520  - Good View

[image]

Comment: Please **STOP** deleting and re-posting the same question again and again!

Comment: Excuse I was made mistake so I put wrong image.. people advice me problem which i resolved. My problem is Write here. :(

Comment: under Display 1 and 2 are links

Comment: you can directly add the images here so it's easier for people to help you.

Comment: @rupps the OP currently doesn't have enough rep.

Comment: and how to solve it?

Comment: The problem may not be in your `ImageView`, but rather in your `drawables`. I'm thinking, since it's different resolutions, that in one `drawable` folder (as for instance `hdpi`) your image has a white background, where in another folder (`mdpi`) it could be transparent.

Comment: All is .gif without background and in xml file  android:src="@mipmap/btup" and transparrent background.

Comment: GIFs? Man, you should really be using PNGs!

Comment: If I use PNG then have these error. 
Error:(317, 58) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@mipmap/btnup').

Comment: Also mind that you're using the **wrong folder**. `mipmap` should only be used for the application icon, not for the other graphics! You should be using the `drawable` buckets, instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is in png format, you can set the color using imageView.setColorFilter("#00000000") method, mind you this will make it totally transparent. the first two 00 are the opacity, while the remaining six are the main color. This works if the image is a monochrome. I mean same color. Otherwise, I will recommend you use an image editor like photoshop, inkscape, sketch, etc to make the image transparent before use. Thanks hope this answers your question.